# Glimpse of QDockWidget in the middle of the screen when gets created

Tags: qt5.5, qdockwidget

When I create a new `QDockWidget`

```
  myWidget = new MyDockWidget(this);
  MyMainWindow::instance()->addDockWidget(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea, mSettings);
```

I can see it in the middle of the screen. After that I can notice it is placed docked to the right. I'm running under debugger so understandably things are slow. Nevertheless end users might run on overbooked machines etc. Could I create the window docked already or hide it until it actually gets docked?

In constructor I have `setupUi(this);` for my `MyDockWidget` with following settings:

```
MyDockWidget->setFloating(true);
MyDockWidget->setFeatures(QDockWidget::AllDockWidgetFeatures);
MyDockWidget->setAllowedAreas(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);
```

So why it appears on center on start? How to fix this?

P.S. If I set dock widget parent to main window it appears undocked - why? What is correct parent? My current  parent is mdi window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed all features, left default like in Dock Widgets Example, and set parent to main window - works fine now.

P.S. Set features DockWidgetFloatable | DockWidgetMovable manually, then same in Designer - works also - some weird bug. Solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `MyDockWidget->setVisible(false);` after you've set all its features.